# Drag and Drop. Файл открывается в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

столкнулся со следующей проблемой - не получается отменить действие браузера по умолчанию при перетаскивании файла с рабочего стола, тобишь он тупо открывает его во вкладке. Смотрел кучу примеров, где люди так же используют метод preventDefault у объекта события, но у меня оно почему-то не работает.

HTML

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table id="drivers-table" class="empty">
        <tr class="caption">
            <td>Дата получения</td>
            <td class="functional">Статус</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nodata">
            <td colspan="2">Записей нет</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="table-triggers">
        <div class="trigger disabled" id="back"></div>
        <div class="trigger-display">1 из 1</div>
        <div class="trigger disabled" id="forward"></div>
        <div class="rowcount">Записей: 0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragndrop"></div>       
</div>
```

JS

```
$.fn.dragAndDrop = function() {
    var elements = this;
    elements.each( function( index ) {
        var table = elements[ index ],
            field = $( $( table ).find( '.dragndrop' ) );
        table.addEventListener( 'dragenter', function() {
            field.show().addClass( 'act' );
            console.log( 'in' );
            return false;
        }, false );
        field[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'dragleave', function() {
            field.hide().removeClass( 'act' );
            console.log( 'out' );
            return false;
        }, false );
        field[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'drop', function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log( e );
        } );
    } );
};

$( '.table-container' ).dragAndDrop();
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` - это что такое? У вас входящий параметр `e`. Вот его и используйте.

Comment: менял код, забыл заменить, тут сам транслятор заругается, а дело в том, что не работает этот метод у меня

Comment: Дело в том, что вам надо привести актуальный код, который у вас не работает. А не обрывки, которые даже не запустятся.

Comment: Вы правы, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все это дело заработало, когда я изменил событие dragenter на dragover, черт знает почему, но заработало